# Monitoring the HTTP(S) calls being made from android App

Tags: penetration-test, android, man-in-the-middle, vulnerability, burp-suite

I want to test for security vulnerabilities in an Android App and hence want to monitor all HTTP(S) calls being made from an Android App.

I have setup BurpSuit in my Laptop and have also set up the proxy in my Android device. After installing the Burp certificate in the user trusted certificates I am able to monitor the HTTP(S) calls properly for Website and almost all apps.

But some apps are showing error by stating **"Could not connect. Please check the internet connection."**.

I am using an Android 5.0 non-rooted device.

Any help would be grateful

Answer (score 1):

Some apps are configured with hard coded CA certificates or internal certificate stores. This means you can't make them trust your certificate by adding a CA in the shared certificate stores. This is quite common security measure e.g. in the financial industry.

Answer (score 0):

You need a rooted device in order to bypass SSL Pinning (Causing this error: **"Could not connect. Please check the internet connection.".**) and preventing you from seeing/intercepting the requests.
There's many tools available on the Xposed Framework that can help.